# Add new column with difference of two rows give SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I have: accumulated number of deaths in a pandas dataframe.

What I need: a new column with the value of difference between two rows (number of deaths by day). So i did the following:

```
df_plot.head()

               date     deaths
1153383     2021-05-04  134
1153384     2021-05-03  120
1153385     2021-05-02  120
1153386     2021-04-30  119
1153387     2021-04-29  114

df_plot.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df_plot.sort_index(ascending=False)

df_plot_2 = df_plot['deaths'].shift() - df_plot['deaths']
df_plot['deaths_by_day'] = df_plot_2
```

But I receive this message. How can I do the new column the correct way?

> ipython-input-46-df83920c83da>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is
> trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using
> .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
> df_plot['deaths_by_day'] = df_plot_2

Thanks.

Comment: Try this: `df_plot_2 = (df_plot['deaths'].shift() - df_plot['deaths']).copy()`

Comment: Same warning. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current example `.copy()` can be used to create a `deep copy` and avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

```
df['death_diff'] = df['deaths'].shift() - df['deaths'].copy()
```

Want to learn more about [SettingWithCopyWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

`.diff()` method can also be used to get `diff` between two rows

```
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df = df.sort_index(ascending=False)
df['death_diff'] = df.deaths.diff().abs()
df
```

**Output**

```
            deaths  death_diff
date        
2021-05-04  134      NaN
2021-05-03  120      14.0
2021-05-02  120      0.0
2021-04-30  119      1.0
2021-04-29  114      5.0
```

Comment: The first approach gives the same warning, but second works fine. Thanks.